# How to define a package's version in a DUB project

Tags: d, dub

I know how to specify version requirements for imported packages in D/DUB project using the list of dependencies in the dub.json file.

But: how do I define the version of a package in it's on dub.json file in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Git tags are the way used for package versioning.

To add version `v1.0`, for example, create a git tag using the following command: `git tag v1.0`.
Dub understands tags as versions for local and online repositories.

I know of no other way to specify versions.

Comment: DUB doesn't seem to recognize them at all. It always uses `~master` (even though there's no `master` branch).

Answer (score 1):

It's managed automatically. If you publish your Github repo to DUB registry, it will fetch all of your version tags from it. See: http://code.dlang.org/publish

Comment: That fine as far as published packages are concerned. But I would like to see a solution for non-published packages in a local repository (or without a git repo at all).

Comment: Dub versioning is tied to Git tagging. If you have tags in your local package's Git repository then it will be understood. I can see that yaz already mentioned it in his answer.